# Finding the integral using divergence theorem without vector field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Use the divergence theorem to evaluate $$\iint_S (x^2 y^2+y^2 z^2+x^2 z^2)\ dS,$$
>   where $S$ is the entire surface of the sphere of unit radius, centered at the origin.

How do I find this? Usually I would find the divergence of the vector field and turn it into a sphere coordinates. But there are no vectors here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit sneaky. On the sphere itself the normal vector is in the radial direction, $\vec{r} = \langle x, y, z \rangle$ (normalized?). Then the integrand

$$x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 = \vec{r} \cdot \langle xy^2, yz^2, zx^2 \rangle$$

Hence the vector field you want is on the far right, which has a nice easy divergence of $y^2 + z^2 + x^2 = r^2$.

Comment: I understand now that the divergence field is $y^2+z^2+x^2$ but I don't understand how it's equal to $r^2$

Comment: $r$, the scalar, is the radial distance from the origin. So $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$. The fact that the div of the vector is $r^2$ is very convenient for integrating over the interior of the sphere.